# Loading dynamic NavItem from API doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I have to create a customized dynamic Navbar for each user depending on the user's role, so I am trying to load (fetch) `NavItem` via an API which take as input a `userid`, the API returns the expected results (into my defined `navdashboard` const array) with success before rendering the `NavItem` component

**BUT NO** `NavItem` is being displayed from my JSON Array, please find the following the code I used:

```
import logoEretraite from 'assets/img/logo/e_retraite.png';
import sidebarBgImage from 'assets/img/slidbar.jpg';
import React from 'react';
import { MdDashboard } from 'react-icons/md';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem, NavLink as BSNavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import bn from 'utils/bemnames';
import API from '../../pages/API';
const api = new API();

const sidebarBackground = {
  //backgroundImage: `url("${sidebarBgImage}")`,
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
};

const navdashboard = [];

api
  .ApiGetTB(sessionStorage.getItem('user_id'))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
    data => {
      data.map(t =>
        navdashboard.push({
          to: '/',
          name: t.nom,
          id: t.id,
          exact: false,
          Icon: MdDashboard,
        }),
      );
    },
    error => {
      console.log('error GetTB');
    },
  );

const bem = bn.create('sidebar');

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <aside className={bem.b()} data-image={sidebarBgImage}>
        <div className={bem.e('background')} style={sidebarBackground} />
        <div className={bem.e('content')}>
          <Navbar>
            <img
              src={logoEretraite}
              width="160"
              height="80"
              className="pr-2"
              alt="#"
            />
          </Navbar>

          <Nav vertical>
            {console.log('navdashboard-->', navdashboard)}
            {navdashboard.map(({ to, name, id, exact, Icon }, index) => (
              <NavItem key={index} className={bem.e('nav-item')}>
                <BSNavLink
                  id={`navItem-${name}-${index}`}
                  className="text-uppercase"
                  tag={NavLink}
                  to={{
                    pathname: to,
                    aboutProps: id,
                  }}
                  activeClassName="active"
                  exact={exact}
                >
                  <Icon className={bem.e('nav-item-icon')} />
                  <span className="">{name}</span>
                </BSNavLink>
              </NavItem>
            ))}
          </Nav>
        </div>
      </aside>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

And this is the result of the console.log results of the rendering section (it shows that the `navdashboard` array isn't empty and it contains the result wanted):

[image: console.log result]

Can some specialists clarify things for me, knowing that when defining  `navdashboard` with static element, like:

```
const navdashboard = [{ to:" ", name:"name", id:"1", exact:false, Icon:MdDashboard }];
```

And when clicking on that static element NAME the result returned by the API got displayed!

[image]

Thanks

Comment: hi , you have to decalre the navdashboard array as part of your state , otherwise all the change will not trigger the reerender , so in order to reerender you component , all changing var should be in the state .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to fetch the API inside the actual component and store the `navdashboard` in a local state. It seems like your React Component is not aware of any of the data changes in `navdashboard` thus always returning empty array.

```
const bem = bn.create('sidebar');

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     navdashboard: []
   };
 }

 componentDidMount() {
   api
     .ApiGetTB(sessionStorage.getItem("user_id"))
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then(
       data => {
         let dashboardData = data.map(t => ({
           to: "/",
           name: t.nom,
           id: t.id,
           exact: false,
           Icon: MdDashboard
         }));
         this.setState({ navdashboard: dashboardData });
       },
       error => {
         console.log("error GetTB");
       }
     );
 }
 render() {
   return (
     <aside className={bem.b()} data-image={sidebarBgImage}>
       <div className={bem.e("background")} style={sidebarBackground} />
       <div className={bem.e("content")}>
         <Navbar>
           <img
             src={logoEretraite}
             width="160"
             height="80"
             className="pr-2"
             alt="#"
           />
         </Navbar>

         <Nav vertical>
           {console.log("navdashboard-->", navdashboard)}
           {navdashboard.map(({ to, name, id, exact, Icon }, index) => (
             <NavItem key={index} className={bem.e("nav-item")}>
               <BSNavLink
                 id={`navItem-${name}-${index}`}
                 className="text-uppercase"
                 tag={NavLink}
                 to={{
                   pathname: to,
                   aboutProps: id
                 }}
                 activeClassName="active"
                 exact={exact}
               >
                 <Icon className={bem.e("nav-item-icon")} />
                 <span className="">{name}</span>
               </BSNavLink>
             </NavItem>
           ))}
         </Nav>
       </div>
     </aside>
   );
 }
}

export default Sidebar;
```